# Change output SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to change the output from this query where the output for Debit_Credit would be 1 and 2 which is 1 for Debit, 2 for Credit. But the output will be display in one column.

```
select t_ocmp as Company, t_otyp as TransactionType, t_odoc as DocumentNo
    , t_leac as LedgerAcc, t_fyer as FiscalYear, t_fprd as FiscalPeriod, t_obat as Batch
    , t_dcdt as DocumentDate, t_bpid as BusinessPartner, t_refr as Reference
    , t_ccty as Tax_Country, t_cvat as Tax_Code, t_ccur as Currency
    , t_amnt as Amount_Foreign, t_amth_1 as Amount_Home_Currency
    , t_dbcr as Debit_Credit
from ....
where t_fprd=10 and t_fyer=2021 and t_leac=11041010;
```

the output will get like this for debit_credit column

[image]

How to change from 1,2 output into Debit,Credit output?

Thanks.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Have you considered using a [`CASE` expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You need to show your desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use case for the different alias for the same column

```
SELECT t_ocmp AS Company, t_otyp AS TransactionType, t_odoc AS DocumentNo
    , t_leac AS LedgerAcc, t_fyer AS FiscalYear, t_fprd AS FiscalPeriod
    , t_obat AS Batch, t_dcdt AS DocumentDate, t_bpid AS BusinessPartner
    , t_refr AS Reference, t_ccty AS Tax_Country, t_cvat AS Tax_Code
    , t_ccur AS Currency, t_amnt AS Amount_Foreign, t_amth_1 AS Amount_Home_Currency 
    , CASE WHEN t_dbcr=1 THEN t_dbcr ELSE 0 END AS credit
    , CASE WHEN t_dbcr= 2 THEN t_dbcr ELSE 0 END AS debit
FROM ...
WHERE t_fprd = 10 AND t_fyer = 2021 AND t_leac = 11041010;
```

Comment: I'm just explaining how to do. And they can consider accordingly.

Comment: The reqiured op is mentioned please if you check the questions.

Comment: Please read the question first? Did you read the email //Debit_Credit would be 1 and 2 which is 1 for Debit, 2 for Credit. But the output will be display in one column.//

Comment: Please if I'm doing any thing wrong in answer please correct me.

Comment: I'm trying to help just. If I have any mistakes please correct so in this way I learn how to answer better way.

Comment: The correction is to only answer questions which are clear. My guess would be that OP wants to show an amount in the debit column, and an amount in the credit column - but if so, which amount? You just end up wasting your own time answering poorly asked questions.

Comment: it's all about misunderstanding. because you understand  other thing and I something else. but I respect always senior devs.

Comment: What you describe is a badly asked question. A well asked question will be clear to all who read it what the OP is looking for.

Comment: `t_dbcr== 1`  equal operator is single `=` sign

Comment: @DaleK you are absolutely right. I and I've  to learn these things to answer in better way.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've try and test the query. Even it is not in 1 column but i appreciate your help in this.

Comment: @AffiqMirza   when I read t he question I understand like this.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly check.

```
select t_ocmp as Company, t_otyp as TransactionType, t_odoc as DocumentNo
    , t_leac as LedgerAcc, t_fyer as FiscalYear, t_fprd as FiscalPeriod, t_obat as Batch
    , t_dcdt as DocumentDate, t_bpid as BusinessPartner, t_refr as Reference
    , t_ccty as Tax_Country, t_cvat as Tax_Code, t_ccur as Currency
    , t_amnt as Amount_Foreign, t_amth_1 as Amount_Home_Currency
    , case when t_dbcr= 1 then 'Debit' when t_dbcr=2 then 'Credit' end as Debit_Credit
from ....
where t_fprd=10 and t_fyer=2021 and t_leac=11041010;
```

Comment: I've try and test. Thanks for your help. The output is what i'm hoping for. Sorry for my poor question.